# App Inventor: If-Statement gives undesirable results

Tags: android, if-statement, boolean-logic, app-inventor

I'm having trouble with an if-statement in my App Inventor code. What I'm trying to do is to prevent a button being enabled and for a notifier to appear when the number in the textbox of txtPasssengerCode.text is either lower than 10000 or greater than 99999, but no matter what numerical value it is, regardless if it's there by default, the condition is ignored and enables the submit button. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the image of the code block

[image]

Comment: If this answers your question, it is good practice to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the answer. If not, you can clarify on what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

> when the number in the textbox of txtPasssengerCode.text is either
>   lower than 10000 **or** greater than 99999

you sould use the **OR** block...

[image]